# Login Issue in Spring Boot using spring boot security

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring boot, and I'm trying spring boot security on my sample application and i'm using MongoDB.

I'm facing some issue. I'm using POSTMAN to test the web services that I developed.

I am not able to hit login method using POSTMAN.

Here is my main application

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(final UserRepository userRepository, final UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
            UserRole usRole = new UserRole();
            usRole.setUroName("Admin");
            usRole.setUroCode("admin");
            usRole.setUroType("admin");
            usRole.setUroCreatedDttm(new DateTime().toString());
            userRoleRepository.save(usRole);

            UserTbl userTbl = new UserTbl();
            userTbl.setEmail("ganeshsagar58@gmail.com");
            userTbl.setUsrPassword("c0b137fe2d792459f26ff763cce44574a5b5ab03");
            userTbl.setFirstName("Ganesh");
            userTbl.setLastName("Bhagavath");
            UserRole userRole = userRoleRepository.findByUroName("Admin");
            userTbl.setUro(userRole);

            userRepository.save(userTbl);
        }
    };
}
}
```

Here is the UserTbl POJO

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class UserTbl
{
@Id
private BigInteger id;

@DBRef
private UserRole uro;

@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max =30)
private String firstName;

@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max =30)
private String lastName;

@NotNull
@Email
private String email;

@NotNull
private String usrPassword;

private DateTime usrCreatedDttm;

private DateTime usrModifiedDttm;

public BigInteger getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigInteger id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public UserRole getUro() {
    return uro;
}

public void setUro(UserRole uro) {
    this.uro = uro;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsrPassword() {
    return usrPassword;
}

public void setUsrPassword(String usrPassword) {
    this.usrPassword = usrPassword;
}

public DateTime getUsrCreatedDttm() {
    return usrCreatedDttm;
}

public void setUsrCreatedDttm(DateTime usrCreatedDttm) {
    this.usrCreatedDttm = usrCreatedDttm;
}

public DateTime getUsrModifiedDttm() {
    return usrModifiedDttm;
}

public void setUsrModifiedDttm(DateTime usrModifiedDttm) {
    this.usrModifiedDttm = usrModifiedDttm;
}   
}
```

Here is the UserRole POJO

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class UserRole 
{
@Id
private BigInteger id;

private String uroName;

private String uroCode;

private String uroType;

private String uroCreatedDttm;

private String uroModifiedDttm;

public BigInteger getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigInteger id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUroName() {
    return uroName;
}

public void setUroName(String uroName) {
    this.uroName = uroName;
}

public String getUroCode() {
    return uroCode;
}

public void setUroCode(String uroCode) {
    this.uroCode = uroCode;
}

public String getUroType() {
    return uroType;
}

public void setUroType(String uroType) {
    this.uroType = uroType;
}

public String getUroCreatedDttm() {
    return uroCreatedDttm;
}

public void setUroCreatedDttm(String uroCreatedDttm) {
    this.uroCreatedDttm = uroCreatedDttm;
}

public String getUroModifiedDttm() {
    return uroModifiedDttm;
}

public void setUroModifiedDttm(String uroModifiedDttm) {
    this.uroModifiedDttm = uroModifiedDttm;
}
}
```

Here is my Websecurity class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  
{
private UserRepository userRepository;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

@Autowired
public void setUserRoleRepository(UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository) 
{
    this.userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
}

@Autowired
public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) 
{
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Autowired
public void setbCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) 
{
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Bean
protected
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserTbl user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);
            if (user != null) {
                return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getUsrPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(userRoleRepository.findByUroName("Admin").getUroName()));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '"
                        + username + "'");
            }
        }

    };
}

public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/posts/**", "/users/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

  }
```

When i hit localhost:8080/login in POSTMAN with POST method (username and password as mentioned in UserTbl), it says

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-03-31T16:18:40.791+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/login"
}
```

My application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=web_application
```

Comment: Do you have POST handling defined in your rest controller?

Comment: Do you get the login page with `GET /login`? Is your `WebSecurityConfig` executed (add a breakpoint)? Could you addd Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level?

Comment: I don't see any URL mappings in the posted code. Where do you define that `POST /login` maps to *some method* that performs a login?

Answer (score 1):

Please check once if you have defined different context explicitly in your application.properties file.

Spring Boot 1.X

```
server.contextPath=/yourAppContext
server.port=8080
```

Spring Boot 2.0

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/yourAppContext
```

If so, you would need to add context path to your request URL,

like ,

```
localhost:8080/yourAppContext/login
```